# Cannot do local remoting

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I can use `Invoke-Command` to another machine on the network.
I have already run `Enable-PSRemoting` as an Administrator.

- PSVersion 5.0.10586.117
- Windows 7 Professional SP1

What am I missing?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.

PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { dir }
[localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error
message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request.
Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests.
Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the
destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service,
run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM
service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConnect,PSSessionStateBroken
```

After setting `DisableStrictNameChecking` to one (1), the same error message appears.

After setting `BackConnectionHostNames` to "localhost" and "ALFRED", the same error message appears.

After setting DisableLoopbackCheck to one (1), the following message appears.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WSManFault
    Message
        ProviderFault
            WSManFault
                Message = WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network connection types on this ma
chine is set to Public. Change the network connection type to either Domain or Private and try again.

Error number:  -2144108183 0x80338169
WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network connection 
types on this machine is set to Public. Ch
ange the network connection type to either Domain or Private and try again.
```

It appears that I do not have permission to change the network type. I am on a corporate VPN. The company.com network is `Domain network`, but the other network is `Public network`. If I cannot change it, then it seems that I cannot get there from here.

Answer (score 1):

It is a security feature called "NTLM loopback check". You can see more details at [MS KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896861/you-receive-error-401.1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrated-authentication-and-is-hosted-on-iis-5.1-or-a-later-version) or at [Marc Lognoul's blog](https://marclsitinfrablog.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/windows-the-confusion-over-disableloopbackcheck-disablestrictnamechecking-and-kerberos/). Briefly, Kerberos cannot be used with "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" or "[::1]" for the remote host name. Authentication fails back to NTLM, and it has exploit related to Loopback IP.

Solution is to disable the loopback check in Registry as explained on that MS page as method 2.

Comment: I have set `DisableStrictNameChecking` to one (1) as described, but still have the same failure. Is there something more that I need to do? Are there other things that a typical corporate environment would "lock down" that would prevent this from working?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You should disable the LoopBackCheck, second part of Microsoft fix. It might even work even without disabling strict name checking. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete WinRM old listener .

winrm delete winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS

first need to create a self-signed certificate and get its thumbprint

1.New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My

Copy the thumbprint to clipboard and run the following command. This command will register the HTTPS listener in WinRM

2.winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname=""; CertificateThumbprint=""}

Add a new firewall rule

```
port=5986
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTPS-In)" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=$port
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your network connection is not set to `public`
2. Setup remoting on localhost

> (1) Start a new powershell window with administrator privilegies (Run as Administrator)
> (2) Retrieve your localhost name with the command: `hostname`
> (3) Enlist this hostname in the list of trusted servers with a command like this:
> `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "<Your hostname from (2) above>"`

3. Activate remoting:
   `Winrm qc`
   `Enable-PSRemoting`
4. Test:
   `Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {hostname}`

Notes:

1. Remoting only works on elevated Powershell
2. To elevate from CMD:
   `powershell -Command "start PowerShell -Verb RunAs"`